# Elasticsearch - return results per 'hit' rather than document

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I am quite new to ES,

I am indexing pdf books using the ingest-attachments-processor-plugin and elasticsearch to return results from my queries as PER hit rather than result PER document. For example, if I am indexing several pdf books, I want to return roughly the paragraph where each match has occurred so that if there are 3 hits in 1 document, there should be 3 results (paragraphs) & if there are 2 hits in another document as well, there should be 5 hits all up. The goal is to create a tool that will retrieve the right answers from these books.

1) Is this possible with elasticsearch? Will Solr be able to solve this problem?
2) How do I get it to return say a paragraph, I don't believe ES understands sentence structure does it? Is there a plugin for this?
3) Should I be looking to parse the document by paragraph (like Watson does with answer units using Document Conversion API) and then index into ES?

Heres the query i'm currently using in python:

```
def execute_es_query(query_input, index, doc_type):
body_query = {
    "stored_fields": [],
    "query": {
        "query_string": {
            "default_field": "attachment.content",
            "query": query_input
        }
    },
    "highlight": {
        "pre_tags": "<span>",
        "post_tags": "</span>",
        "fields": {
            "attachment.content":{}
        }
    }
}
response = es_client.search(index= index, doc_type = doc_type, body = body_query)
return response['hits']['hits']

def fetch_response(response):
num = 1
for i in response:
    print "Result:", num
    for j in i['highlight']['attachment.content']:
        print j
    print "\n"
    num+=1
```

Comment: Do you want ES to return only paragraph field in the result ,instead of whole document ?

Comment: Yes, like a paragraph in a book as EACH result rather than the whole document as one result.

Answer (score 0):

If you're storing paragraphs as [nested](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html) or [child](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-parent-field.html) documents, you can use the [inner-hits feature](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-inner-hits.html).

Derived from the docs:

```
{
  "query" : {
    "nested" : {
      "path" : "attachment",
        "query_string": {
          "default_field": "attachment.content",
          "query": query_input
         }
         "inner_hits" : {} 
       }
     }
}
```

The response will then contain a field named `inner_hits` in every document returned, containing matched paragraphs for every document returned.

This method will still return documents as primary search results. If you want to search paragraphs, my suggestion would be to index them as a separate type.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I have to parse the full document as paragraphs before indexing.